# How to swap slot using RM Powershell on Azure web app?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

Following [this link on how to swap slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing#azure-powershell-cmdlets-for-deployment-slots), with the following script:

```
$ParametersObject = @{
  targetSlot  = "production";
};
$Name = "testsite312345345";
$SourceSlot = "staging";    

Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots" -ResourceName "$Name/$SourceSlot" -Action slotsswap -Parameters $ParametersObject -ApiVersion 2015-07-01 -Force -Verbose;
```

I get this output, with the key part being `Property id 'production' at path 'targetSlot' is invalid`:

VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Invoking the 'slotsswap' action on the resource." on target "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-7649-4a3e-bc8b-xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/testsite312345345/slots/staging".
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction : The pipeline has been stopped.
+ Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction], PipelineStoppedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.InvokAzureResourceActionCmdlet

Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction : LinkedInvalidPropertyId : Property id 'production' at path 'targetSlot' is invalid. Expect either resource name e.g. 'myResource' or qualified resource name e.g. 
'myParent/myResource'.

- Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots ...
- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  - CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction], ErrorResponseMessageException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : LinkedInvalidPropertyId,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.InvokAzureResourceActionCmdlet

I have tried numerous formats for the `$TargetSlot` production value but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the Resource Group Name: `-ResourceGroupName MyRg`

Wasn't that obvious from the error message? I know, I know, it's bad... ;)

Comment: Yes I just performed a successful swap before coming back to check this post :(. Thanks David